# All Usernames in a specific Role in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotusscript

I need to get all the username of a specific role so that I would be able to send a mail to all user's who has that role access. How would I able to accomplish this task?

I saw this link,

[How do I get all users who have a specified role?](http://dbaspot.com/lotus-notes-programmer/395359-how-do-i-get-all-users-who-have-specified-role.html)

Is there no other way to get all the valid username that can be used in the SendTo? Without having this problem? Though I didn't try the NotesACL. I am new in Lotus Notes Development.

Comment: What do you mean by "this problem"?  That post claims that iterating through the ACL entries seems to be a performance killer, but it doesn't cite any data to support that claim. It should not be slow at all.

Comment: Hi Richard, Well basically it's my fault since when I read that I still have no idea about notesACL, but I'm really in a rush so I asked this question. Now I clearly understand how notesACL works with the help of Knut. I really have a long road to go in learning notes development been here for just 3 weeks. Thanks a lot. God Bless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a bit influence how ACL entries are look like then you should be able to achieve a good solution. Following code collects all entries in ACL with the certain role **and** accepts only those entries which are of type `Person` or `Person group`.

```
Function GetRoleMembers(roleName As String) As String
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim acl As NotesACL
    Dim entry As NotesACLEntry
    Dim sMembers As String 
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set acl = db.ACL
    sMembers = ""
    Set entry = acl.GetFirstEntry
    While Not ( entry Is Nothing )
        If entry.IsRoleEnabled( roleName ) And entry.IsPerson Then
            sMembers = sMembers + entry.Name & ","
        End If
        Set entry = acl.GetNextEntry( entry )
    Wend
    GetRoleMembers = sMembers
End Function
```

The Function returns a comma separated list of all persons and groups with given role. You can test this function with

```
Print GetRoleMembers("[Test]")
```

Make sure that users whom you want to send emails are assigned to type `Person` or `Person group`. You can set user's type in ACL

[image]

Comment: Hi Knut Herrmann, Thanks a lot. It worked and I'm sorry if this question is so simple. Guess I still need to study more, though I asked this since I have no more time to learn for the deadline. But because of you I clearly understood the NotesACL which I never used this past 3 works after starting in lotus notes development. God Bless.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a good decision to develop with IBM Notes Domino. I've been doing it since 1992. Have fun!